# Move environment variables from local to server

Tags: environment-variables

Let's say I'm connecting to a server, as in the example below. How can I give the remote server the environment variables I'm using remotely?

`${GITHUB_TOKEN}` is available and working fine locally. But I can't seem to find a way to pass it to my remote.

```
# the variables is on the local as ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
ssh admin@mydomain.tld <<'EOF'
   # Now I want to use it on the remote
   git clone https://${GIHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/myrepo.git
EOF
```

I'm doing this as part of deployment on a circle-ci container, if you need the context.

I've tried `-oSendEnv=GITHUB_TOKEN`, that didn't seem to work.

Comment: i think what you are asking has already been asked on Stackoverflow have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh

Comment: Yes, I've tried with SendEnv, but I can't seem to get it to work. If you could show a complete example if would be helpful.